# How to Create a jar file from github project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want a jar file for the project `https://github.com/klout/brickhouse` but I don't see any link on the site which gives me jar file. There is a link on right menu to download the project as zip file.

I found similar question [How to create single jar file from github tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300813/how-to-create-single-jar-file-from-github-tree), but I have dependencies in the pom.xml. I'm using eclipse and win-7. One way I can think of is create a new project in eclipse, add all java packages and files, get all dependency jar files from pom.xml, download them and add to class path. But this will be a lengthy process. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This should be as simple as running `mvn package` in your local clone of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late in responding, but Brickhouse has a separate Downloads page in the wiki

https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Downloads

Also, if you are using maven or ivy, it should be available in the sonatype public repo.
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/klout/brickhouse/

If you are using maven to build a jar assembly, add the following lines in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.klout</groupId>
        <artifactId>brickhouse</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 15):

There's a [Getting Started](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse#getting-started) section in the project's README that shows the steps to follow to do just that. I just tried them and they work just fine:

```
$ git clone http://github.com/klout/brickhouse
$ cd brickhouse
$ mvn package
$ cd target
$ dir
```

That's it! You have to have Maven installed of course.

Comment: This method requires `POM` file to be in a project, otherwise it will throw an error: `[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Library). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: If you don't have `pom.xml`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203395/how-to-get-a-jar-from-github-project.