# How to get a jar from github project?

Tags: java, android

I want to use kSoap2-android library from the official site http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html, but I don't know how can I make a jar from the github project https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you just need to run the mvnw(.bat)

Comment: @shilovk and others. This is not a duplicate. Eclipse is not suitable here. For Android Studio you should use another way.

Comment: not duplicate, the linked duplicate solution is for eclipse, android studio is different, reddit mods everywhere~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project has a pom.xml so it can be built with maven.

It also has a maven wrapper script (mvnw), so you can run it without even having maven on your computer.

EDIT : sorry, I did not see that you only wanted one subproject.
try :

```
mvn install -pl ksoap2-android -am
```

Comment: I'm new to maven... Do you mean to run in bash something like this `mvn clean tomcat7:redeploy`? I've tried but it gives me some errors...

Comment: You need to either run mvn package in a shell or just execute the mvnw (if you are on UNIX, or mvnw.bat if you are on windows)

Comment: I ran `mvn package` but it made a jar for each package in the project. Can i avoid this?

Comment: Thanks for try, but the project is called *ksoap2-android-master* and has a package called *ksoap2-android*. Using `mvn install -pl ksoap2-android -am` generate a `jar` only on the *ksoap2-android* package.

Comment: @MateutAlin yes it's what it does. But what do you want ? That maven magically creates a single jar containing all sub-projects ? You have to rewrite the pom.xml to make it do what you want (which is not what the developers intended). They have a repository with several subprojects because they answer different needs.

Comment: I saw an earlier version of the same project (containing the sub-projects) that was packed in a single jar and I thought that it's some magic that I don't understand. Anyway, thank you for clarifying me and sorry for this silly question.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this step by step procedure to get .jar:

1. Click the Clone or download button, and click Download ZIP.
2. Extract the downloaded zip file to a folder somewhere.
3. Go into the folder that contains the src directory and the gradlew files
4. Shift-right-click, click Open command window here
5. Enter gradlew.bat setupDecompWorkspace
6. Enter gradlew.bat shadowJar
7. The JAR file is in the build folder, inside the libs folder.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: There are no gradlew files. But thanks for try

Comment: Check your project folder it is in there

Comment: There are main, build and other folders are there

Comment: Thanks. `gradlew build` helped me.

Comment: Your welcome. Hope it helps others as well.